# Where to add offset?

Tags: loop, recent-posts

I want to use the offset function to skip the first post and I have this code inside which I need to put an offside=1 , but wherever I insert it, I receive the error...any idea where I can add it inside this code below?

```
<?php 
$recent = new WP_Query( array( 
    'tag' => get_option('gd_slider_tags'), 
    'showposts' => get_option('gd_slider_num')) 
); 
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
```

Comment: have you really been using `offside` instead of `offset`?

Comment: Lol , no i just seen this ...i m tired and the english is not my first languange, and i m watching a game.Once again , thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$recent = new WP_Query( array( 
    'tag' => get_option('gd_slider_tags'), 
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('gd_slider_num'),
    'offset' => 1) 
); 
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
```

Comment: `showposts` is deprecated

Comment: I was going to say : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW ...still nothing..then i see you edited, and the new code works.Thanks

Comment: @JMa - good spot, fixed.